# How To Fetch Related Category Products in Python Django From Database Table?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have create some apps inside my Django project, they are called `Coupon` and `Store`, both of them are related to each other. For instance, there can be many coupons related a store (Coupon1, Coupon2 belongs to Store1).

```
class Coupon(models.Model): 
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING) 
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    ...

    def __str__(self): 
        return self.title

class Store(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    description = models.TextField(blank=True) 
    ...

    def __str__(self): 
        return self.name
```

What I'd like to accomplish is when a user clicks on any of these coupons (Coupon1, Coupon2), the user should see a list of all coupons in a seperate view which is related to Store1.

How should I do it ?

Comment: In order to give you a relevant answer, can you share your model?

Comment: class Coupon(models.Model):
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING) 
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    gift_type = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    expire_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

Comment: class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    rating = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True) 
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

Comment: First one is Coupons Model
Second is Store Model

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand what you want, it's gonna be that way:

```
# Get the Coupon1 instance
coupon = Coupon.objects.filter(name="Coupon1")
# Get all coupons related to the same store as Coupon1
coupons_from_same_store = Coupon.objects.filter(store=coupon.store)
```

Comment: This is something when you call related coupons in specific view, But i want when user click on any coupon which is related Store1 then there should be view with all Coupons which belongs to Store1

Comment: So, that is what this code do: it gets all coupons from the store of the current coupon. In your template, put a link calling this view with the coupon as argument.

Comment: this is confusing ( it gets all coupons from the store of the current coupon )
Let me clear more, I can see many coupons listed in my site and when i click on any coupon suppose i clicked on coupon1 which belongs to store1 here coupon1 is product and store1 is category, ok after clicking on coupon1 it should show all coupons which related to store1.

Comment: So, you should do this request using javascript on your template, especially [ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) or the [axios library](https://github.com/axios/axios).
For further informations on how to make an ajax call or an axios request, I recommend you open an other question.

Answer (score 0):

let's say I have the ID of the coupon in URL called `coupen_id`,

```
coupen = Coupen.objects.get(pk=coupen_id)
coupons = Coupon.objects.filter(store_id=coupen.store.id)
print(store_id)
```

Comment: This something make sense, Like you mean i have list of coupons Some of these belongs to Store1 and some belongs to Store2  when i click on any coupon which is related to Store1 or Store2 any of these stores, Then there should be open view where user will be able to see coupons related to what Store coupon item he clicked simple.

Comment: can you guide on using ajax with that?